# Validation/Format of display-name in from header

Tags: smtp, rfc, rfc2822

I need to know what are the rules for validation/format from(`name-addr`) field in the email.
In rfc explained the format of `name-addr`, but goes into detail about the `display-name`.

Like this:

```
From: John Q. Public <JQP@bar.com>
```

I want to know the characters and length allowed.
How do I know that `John Q. Public` has valid characters?
Should I allow only printable US-ASCII characters ?

I consulted the [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4) and not found on the specific format of a display name

Comment: Any chance you could upvote & accept my answer? Thanks.

Comment: @jstedfast - I accepted your answer, thank you very much for your attention. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is all defined in the rfc you linked to in your question (btw, the newer version of this document is [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)):

```
display-name    =       phrase
phrase          =       1*word / obs-phrase
word            =       atom / quoted-string
atom            =       [CFWS] 1*atext [CFWS]
atext           =       ALPHA / DIGIT / ; Any character except controls,
                        "!" / "#" /     ;  SP, and specials.
                        "$" / "%" /     ;  Used for atoms
                        "&" / "'" /
                        "*" / "+" /
                        "-" / "/" /
                        "=" / "?" /
                        "^" / "_" /
                        "`" / "{" /
                        "|" / "}" /
                        "~"
specials        =       "(" / ")" /     ; Special characters used in
                        "<" / ">" /     ;  other parts of the syntax
                        "[" / "]" /
                        ":" / ";" /
                        "@" / "\" /
                        "," / "." /
                        DQUOTE
```

You have to jump around in the document a bit to find the definitions of each of these token types, but they are all there.

Once you have the definitions, all you need to do is scan over your name string and see if it consists only of the valid characters.

According to the definitions, a `display-name` is a `phrase` and a `phrase` is 1-or-more `word` tokens (or an `obs-word` which I'll ignore for now to make this explanation simpler).

A `word` token can be either an `atom` or a `quoted-string`.

In your example, `John Q. Public` contains a `special` character, `"."`, which cannot appear within an `atom` token. What about a `quoted-string` token? Well, let's see...

```
quoted-string   =       [CFWS]
                        DQUOTE *([FWS] qcontent) [FWS] DQUOTE
                        [CFWS]
qcontent        =       qtext / quoted-pair
qtext           =       NO-WS-CTL /     ; Non white space controls
                        %d33 /          ; The rest of the US-ASCII
                        %d35-91 /       ;  characters not including "\"
                        %d93-126        ;  or the quote character
```

Based on this, we can tell that a `"."` is allowed within a quoted-string, so... the correct formatting for your `display-name` can be any of the following:

```
From: "John Q. Public" <JQB@bar.com>
```

or

```
From: John "Q." Public <JQB@bar.com>
```

or

```
From: "John Q." Public <JQB@bar.com>
```

or

```
From: John "Q. Public" <JQB@bar.com>
```

Any one of those will work.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Thank you for spending the time to compile this into one single concise definition!

Comment: Thanks also for a helpful demonstration of how to read and compose/decompose lexical token rules from a spec. That was eye-opening.